# Gamma parameterization and how to randomly generate $\sigma$'s for use in `rnorm(n, $\mu$, $\sigma$)`

Tags: r, prior, gamma-distribution, jags, bugs

Say I have a normal distribution parameterized with a mean ($\mu$) and precision ($\tau = 1/\sigma^2)$. In JAGS, I would specify a prior for $\tau$ as `tau ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)`. Working in R, I want to randomly generate values that would follow the distribution that I've specified in JAGS.

I know that `rgamma` is the function for drawing values from the gamma distribution. I also know that JAGS parameterizes values differently from R.

[In R, the gamma density function is parameterized as](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html) $$f(x)= 1/(s^a \Gamma(a)) x^{a-1} e^{-x/s}$$ where $a$ is the `shape` argument in `rgamma`, and $s$ is the `scale` argument in `rgamma`.

[In JAGS, the gamma density function is parameterized as](http://people.math.aau.dk/~kkb/Undervisning/Bayes14/sorenh/docs/jags_user_manual.pdf) $$\frac{\lambda^rx^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(r)}$$ where $\lambda>0$ and $r>0$.

I think I keep screwing up the algebra with the different parameterizations, and I'm getting confused as to what values I should specify for the arguments of `rgamma` in R.

**I think the correct answer is `rgamma(n=1, shape=0.01, rate=1/0.01)`**; is this the correct way to generate a single value from the same `~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)` distribution I specified in JAGS? The greater idea here is to pick a reasonable distribution/ function in R for generating precision values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gamma density function in R,

$$f_\mathrm R(x)= 1/(s^a \Gamma(a)) x^{a-1} e^{-x/s},$$

where $a$ is the `shape` parameter  and $s$ is the `scale` parameter, corresponds to the the `dgamma` function in JAGS,

$$f_\mathrm{JAGS}(x) = \frac{\lambda^rx^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(r)},$$

where $r$ is the `r` paramater and $\lambda$ is the `lambda` parameter,

when we set

$$a = r, s = \frac{1}{\lambda}.$$

If you use these parameters in the R formula, you can see the correspondence:

$$f_\mathrm R(x)= 1\bigg/\left(\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^r \Gamma(r)\right) x^{r-1} e^{-\lambda x}$$

$$= \frac{\lambda^rx^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(r)}$$

$$= f_\mathrm{JAGS}(x).$$

Hence, the equivalent to a random variable distributed `~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)` in JAGS is **`rgamma(n = 1, shape = 0.01, scale = 1 / 0.01)`** in R. The latter one is equivalent to **`rgamma(n = 1, shape = 0.01, rate = 0.01)`**.